# Запуск поочередной анимации в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, анимация, android-fragment, android-threads

Я не могу запустить поочередную анимацию.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < txts.size(); i++) {
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) txts.get(i).getBackground();
        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(4000);
        animationDrawable.start();
        try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sasha(String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
```

Я пытался поместить этот код в onStart, onCreate, onResume. Сначала появляется черный экран, т.е. ждет пока цикл остановится и только потом запускает все анимации разом.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про AnimatorSet: [тут](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/livetyping/blog/274135/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426052/android-animatorset-object-animator-bounce-animation-chain-is-amalgamating) и конечно же гул, там всё есть

```
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
List list = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < txts.size(); i++) {
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) txts.get(i).getBackground();
        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(4000);
        list.add(animationDrawable);
    }

as.playSequentially(list);
//as.setDuration(6000); точно не помню, нужно ли здесь - методом эксперемнта пробуйте
as.start(); // и старт там где вам нужно выполнить эту анимацию.
```

P.S. Вы бы для начала добавили кнопку и запускали анимацию по кнопке, и понятнее будет и нагляднее

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да вот только студия выдает ошибку: AnimationDrawable cannot be cast to android.animation.Animator

Comment: @СашаКрисс Смотрите, тут какая ситуация, есть библиотека Animation и Animator, Animation сейчас использовать не рекомендуют из-за утечек памяти, вместо неё желательно использовать Animator и не обратил что у вас используется именно animation. На днях исправлю. Уточните в вопросе, что именно должно получиться.